# How to insert data into temporary table from the table having encrypted columns in sql server

Tags: sql-server, insert, encryption, temporary-tables, always-encrypted

I am trying to insert data into a temporary table(**#table1**) from the table(**table2**) having encrypted column in it.
I am getting below error while trying to insert data into temporary table from the table having encrypted column.

1. I have one encrypted column in **table2**.
2. I want to insert the data from table2 into #table1(temporary table).

> Cannot create table '#table1' since it references a column encryption
> key from a different database.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: If it is selective data, have you tried temporary table variable instead?